# What is the difference between `fastboot reboot bootloader` and `fastboot reboot-bootloader`?

Tags: fastboot, bootloader

`fastboot` provides two methods for rebooting a device into the bootloader:

- `fastboot reboot bootloader`
- `fastboot reboot-bootloader`

How (and whyy) are these two commands different and when is it appropriate to use each?

Comment: it is just because some developers did mistake, only one of this works it's different between phones

Comment: It looks like different references give different commands.  I would suspect that the hyphen is a typo.  Have you tried them both ?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to this question [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/heads/master/fastboot/README.md). To quote from the source.

> reboot : Reboot the device.
>
> reboot-bootloader : Reboot back into the bootloader.                   Useful for upgrade processes that require upgrading the bootloader and then upgrading other partitions using the new bootloader.